# regex extract string value with space from tab delimited text line

Tags: regex

I have text line in following format

> 1344232458000  5260    2   abcdef  e168ae6ec0804987b1ce723465cbbb50    1   -   -   -   -   125,126,127 2   -   22  b53a59973665405180e3ed015e094195    77  66  -   98  -   -   -   -   -   16953   Message Recall  79112

I need to extract string `Message Recall` at index 26.

Comment: i.e. `e168ae6ec0804987b1ce723465cbbb50` ? More conditions please. What your text could be, which parts are always present, which are not?

Comment: i have written !?(\\S+\\t+){26} regex to parse value but not working

Comment: line contains tab delimited fields. fields are optional. if the value is not present will be replaced with "-" before entering to system.

Comment: So required string is on 5'th place always?

Comment: yes all the values are at fixed position for a given text line separated by tab.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If required string is always on the same place (for example always fifth) you mustn't use regexp. Just break your string by delimiters (in your case " ") to get an array (I'm sure Java has such basic method) and then access required part by array index.

I'm not familiar with java, but here is PHP working example for your task (assuming we want to get `e168ae6ec0804987b1ce723465cbbb50` -  5th):

```
$string = '1344232458000 5260 2 abcdef e168ae6ec0804987b1ce723465cbbb50 1 - - - - 125,126,127 2 - 22';

$array = explode(' ', string);

var_dump($array[4]); // prints `e168ae6ec0804987b1ce723465cbbb50`
```

Comment: issue is input file contains GBs of data. parsing the string with given delimiter will work but will really slow down the performance of a system and hence looking for a regex to extract value.

Comment: Using regex on input file containing GBs of data would be soooo slow. If you have to parse every line of data - split file line-by-line and process every line. If you have to get required string from only beginning of file, read for example first 1000 bytes from file and process them.